# OSX Routing Between 2 NICs on 2 separate hosts

Tags: networking, macos, routing

A little background: I am building a box that I can ship to a venue that has a Mac Mini and a Sony PTZ camera that connects directly to it via ethernet. I am using a secondary NIC to connect the camera, primary NIC connects to the venues network. From that mac (locally logged in), I can connect, send UDP commands to the camera and everything works.

Now what I want to do, is be able to issue commands from my OTHER mac on the same network and sort of "Proxy" traffic from the primary NIC, to the camera NIC and eventually to the camera. Ultimately these will be connected over a VPN, but for now I am trying to get it working on the same local area network.

Here is a diagram:
[image]

- The camera, is directly connected to mac 1 via ETH2 and the camera has an IP of 192.168.2.50. That NIC has an IP of 192.168.2.15
- Mac 1 also connects to the LAN/Internet with Eth1 and it's IP is 192.168.1.147
- I want to be able to hit 192.168.2.50 from Mac 2. I tried adding static routes on Mac 2 but it wouldn't work.

**Things I have tried:**
I added the following route on Mac 2.

```
sudo route -n add 192.168.2.50 192.168.1.147
```

When I add this route and run a TraceRoute every hop times out.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: @music2myear It's hard to find any examples of this exact case. I have tried a bunch of static routes. I will update the question.

Comment: You will need to enable, and allow in firewall, IP forwarding on MAC 1. Besides you probably need to configure source NAT on it for MAC 2 (unless you can configure return route on the camera; or unless it uses MAC 1 as its default gateway anyway).